# How to make the body width equal to the device-width automatically in CSS3 media query?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm doing a mobile website now and trying to target different devices using CSS3 media queries. Part of my code is as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
body {
    width: 320px;
}
/* some other style */  
}
```

As you can see, I have to set the body width explicitly to make sure it doesn't show the width I set for desktop in my normal css, which is 920px. I'm wondering if there is any way that the body width can be set automatically to the device width and I don't need to  set this manually every time I create a new `@media`.

By the way, I also add the following code inside my `head` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Is something wrong with `width: 100%`?

Comment: `width: 100%` does not work for adsense responsive ad units...  Must define size

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use `width: auto;`

Difference between `width: 100%;` and `width: auto;` is that outer width for 100% is `100% + padding-left + padding-right`, inner `100%`. Outer width of `width: auto` is `100%`, inner width is `100% - padding-left - padding-right` if and only if `display` is `block` and no `float` is set (and no floated element without clear is before).

Comment: Thanks, man!One more question, as I set all the items width inside the body tag by percentage, when I zoom in, it seems that those items' width are still the same, but what I wanna do is to make the width of them zoomed in too, how could I achieve this?

Comment: You can set only `min-width` property to fixed value eg. `min-width: 320px;`. Set it just for smallest supported `@media` size as a minimum allowed size. You can set `min-width` for any element also, but it is good practice set it always for body because floated elements should change their position.

Comment: Doesn't always work. For example if you try to set the bootstrap popover width using this. Use the width: 100vw; below from @sh3nan1gans

Answer (score 44):

You can also use

```
width: 100vw;
```

That will set the element to 100% of the viewport's width. 
You might want to check your browsers' compatibility before adding:
http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

More info on viewport sizing:
https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: This is one of the best tips I have seen when using CSS in modern browsers. This is extremely useful and can solve many complex problems. For example, when you have a scrolling div that is wider than the viewport  and you want to limit the child div inside this div to a percent of view port width. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I messed with a lot of different solutions and this is the one that came out best for me.

```
:root {
Max-width:100%;
}

body { min-height:100vh;
}
```

From here you’ll add in (max-width:100%;) on each child element from the root. Root sets it as the uppermost parent element causing everything to be able to set to 100% width. If the element above the child element doesn’t have 100% width it won’t apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).