# Set two different viewports setting via CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, device-width

I'm trying to set two different viewport settings for different browser widths.

The first viewport setting is for devices wider than 680px width (especially for iPad and desktop devices):

The second viewport for devices under 680px width:

I was trying to solve the viewport width CSS media queries, to be able to ask for the current browser width:

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 681px) {
 @viewport {
width: 1160px;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
 @viewport {
width: width=device-width;
 zoom: 1;
}
}
```

But it seems, my viewports were ignored by the browser. Someone has an idea, what the problem could be?

Thank you guys!

Comment: This isn't WordPress specific but Javascript / CSS specific and better asked over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: `width: width=device-width;` isn't even valid.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Device Adaptation (the @viewport at-rule) is not well supported at this time. Specifically it is not supported on Safari desktop or mobile and is only supported in mobile Chrome since version 29. IE/Edge require a special prefix. So you should not rely on it for your current development as it may not behave consistently across platforms.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport

Answer (score 0):

What about to try:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 681px) {
 @viewport {
  width: 1160px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
 @viewport {
  /* That will set the element to 100% of the viewport's width */
  width: width: 100vw; 
  zoom: 1;
 }
}
```

You can see this question: [How to make the body width equal to the device-width automatically in CSS3 media query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095833/how-to-make-the-body-width-equal-to-the-device-width-automatically-in-css3-media)

And this CSS-Tricks post: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Hope it helps